# Set up Contribution page to only accept recurring contributions?

Tags: civicontribute, contribution-page, recurring-contributions

We would like to set up a contribution page that only accepts monthly recurring contributions. Is there a simple way to do this in CiviCRM?

This contribution page would be associated with a Campaign, and we would like to be able to use the contribution widget to display how many monthly recurring contributions we have received and count them towards a monthly contribution goal. For example, we would like to fundraise to cover a monthly cost, like rent, and set up the widget to display the total monthly cost, and the portion covered by monthly recurring donations.

We are using CiviCRM 5.6.0 with Drupal 7.

Comment: we had to tweak a widget for a PCP to show the 'monthly' total for recurring contributions - if you need a hand, sing out and we may be able to share what we did, but unsure how applicable it would be

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Black Fly Solutions has an extension called [ca.civicrm.contribution_recur](https://github.com/adixon/ca.civicrm.contributionrecur) that enhances recurring contributions.  One option it adds is to force recurring payments, which should meet your first need.

The contribution widget only shows total contributions, not total of recurring contributions.  To show that you'd need a bit of custom work.

Comment: Thanks, looks promising. But the documentation seems to suggest that the force recurring contributions option must be enabled for all contribution pages that contain the recurring option. I might be reading that wrong, but if that's the case this wouldn't work for us.

Comment: @KMRD sorry to hear that!  If you have a developer available, it's probably a quick change that can be made.  If not, you may want to reach out to Alan Dixon at Black Fly for a quote.  Or any other CiviCRM provider if Alan's not available!

Comment: I'll reach out to Alan. Thanks @Jon for your help!

Comment: The ability to set the force recur option per contribution page is implemented. Thanks Jon!

Answer (score 4):

Similar to Black Fly's extension, I published a basic extension that only adds an option to force recurring donations (per contribution page setting). I would still recommend first testing Alan's extension, it has a much more complete feature set. I'm just adding this as an alternative, I wanted to implement it a bit differently.

[image: force recurring settings]

To download: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/forcerecurring

Comment: Did you forget to link to the extension page? This one? https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/forcerecurring

Comment: Yep, thank you! I updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

It might be possible to use Webform CiviCRM  (https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm) to set up a page that forces recurring contributions. Conditionals can be set up to control terms, # of installments, and frequency of installments. I usually put those into a fieldset hidden from the end-user. If I recall correctly, it should be possible to set up open-ended recurring payments (term: 0). With this approach, you have more control over theming and placement and can do it for just one contribution page. Downside is increased overhead and training.